# Как изменить улучшить код?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, инспекция-кода

Есть игра, много персонажей. У каждого есть свои уникальные приемы, например

```
Бутылка шампанского

1. метнуть пробкой сквозь противника перекручиваясь через себя
2. залить пол алкоголем, заставив противника подскользнуться упасть
```

или

```
Варвар

1. Кинуть топор вверх, через секунду топор прилетит в голову сопернику
2. Усыпить соперника рогом шляпы в глаз
```

Для каждого персонажа для кастомных приемов есть свой класс, в котором есть три метода: `beforeAttack`, `afterAttack`, `UpdateAttack`. Где `beforeAttack` и  `afterAttack` вызываются лишь один раз до приема и после, а `UpdateAttack` обновляется 1 раз в кадр (то есть много). Эти классы наследуются от главного, который и контролирует процесс, примерно выглядит так:

```
abstract class CommonCustom {

    public virtual void beforeAttack() {}
    public virtual void afterAttack() {}
    public virtual void UpdateAttack() {}

    public virtual void ApplyAll() {
        // тут некое условие, чтоб этот метод вызывался лишь раз!
        beforeAttack();

        // вызывается много раз пока идет прием
        UpdateAttack();

        // тут некое условие, чтоб этот метод вызывался лишь раз!
        afterAttack();
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы: т.к. у меня есть три метода и у каждого персонажа может быть несколько приемов, то получается так, что в каждом методе я пишу `switch/case`, например:

```
class Test : CommonCustom {
    public virtual void beforeAttack() {
        switch attackType {
            case beerAttack: //do smth
                 break;
            case capAttack: //do smth
                 break;
            // и т.д.
        }
    }
    public virtual void afterAttack() {
        switch attackType {
            case beerAttack: //do smth
                 break;
            case capAttack: //do smth
                 break;
            // и т.д.
        }
    }
    public virtual void UpdateAttack() {
        switch attackType {
            case beerAttack: //do smth
                 break;
            case capAttack: //do smth
                 break;
            // и т.д.
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли что-то как-то сделать, чтоб не писать в каждом методе swith, а как-то единообразить всё это дело? Может быть как-то добавить еще классы, которые надо имплементировать или еще что-то.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вам [сюда](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov тут тоже это позволительно. Тут даже метка есть. Я её не поставил правда. Не уверен что конкретно надо ставить сейчас к вопросу

Comment: Непонятно, что за класс Test и почему он так делает. Его логику в предметной области опишите.

Comment: @Monk что значит почему он так делает? Ну есть главный класс с логикой игры в котором есть метод `UpdateAll` который вызывается один раз в кадр. (т.е. 60 раз в секунду)... в нем вызывается метод `ApplyAll()` объекта (игрока), которым как раз является персонаж с классом `Test`. Т.к. унаследован от `CommonCustom` то у него тоже срабатывает `ApplyAll()` и заставляет срабатывать эти три метода.

Comment: @Kromster вся логика различных общих действий или работы контроллеров или работы конфига  описаны в разных классах. А что дело касается индивидуальных способностей/умений персонажа - их никак унифицировать нельзя, т.к. у всех они совсем совсем разные и состоят из разных вещей и привести к общему знаменателю не получится. Поэтому решил сделать для совсем кастомных индивидульальных приемов каждого персонажа создать отдельные классы, в котором будет прописана логика этих самых индивидуальных приемов. Например комбинация -> -> <- A взрывает бомбу из руки крутясь через себя юзая свойства приема

Comment: Таки у вас у теста должна быть коллекция модификатов\предметов, с общим интерфейсом, которые и надо вызывать в `ApplyAll`, а не case строчить. Выдали шмотку юзверю - добавили её в коллекцию, теперь она тоже вызывается.

Comment: @Kromster в начале так и думал. Потом подумал что пара сотен классов (пара десятков персов с десятком ударов) это будет много и решил case юзать. Типа менее удобно, зато всё свое ношу с собой.

Comment: @user221013 перенес все в ответ и дополнил.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал интерфейс IAttack:

```
public interface IAttack
{
    public void PreAttack();
    public void Attack();
    public void PostAttack();
}
```

BeerAttack и другие реализуют этот интерфейс:

```
public class BeerAttack : IAttack
{
    public void PreAttack()
    {
        //специфическая логика пива
    }
    public void Attack()
    {
        //специфическая логика пива
    }
    public void PostAttack()
    {
        //специфическая логика пива
    }
}
```

Потом вот так:

```
class Test : CommonCustom {
    public virtual void beforeAttack(IAttack attack) 
    {
        attack.PreAttack();
    }
    public virtual void afterAttack(IAttack attack) 
    {
        attack.PostAttack();
    }
    public virtual void UpdateAttack(IAttack attack) 
    {
        attack.Attack();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

При любом раскладе вам придется расписать эту пару сотен сценариев, в скриптах ли, классах, кейсах.. Ваша задача найти такой вариант, который будет максимально удобным, с минимумом повторений и возможностей ошибиться, с необходимой вам степенью кастомизации и масштабируемости. Напишите десять сценариев, вычлените все общее. Выберите вариант.

- Кейсы, и как их развитие - Полиморфизм
  Сделать класс действия, отнаследовать от него классы действий (по типам). Использовать классы действий согласно типам действий прописанным в данных. Удобно кодить, но неудобно настраивать.
- Дата-дривен
  Когда вы все действия пропишите в данных игры и будет один класс который будет их выполнять. Достаточно жесткая структура. Что-то среднее межды хардкодом и скриптами (см. ниже)
- Скриптовые языки,
  типа Lua. Отличные возможности по моддингу игры и масштабируемости. Не нужно перекомпилировать чтобы изменить какую-то мелочь.